# Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm quite new to react doing a course with create-react-app where I need to npm run eject. When I do I get a error:

```
Remove untracked files, stash or commit any changes, and try again.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 eject: `react-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I took some advice, deletes the node modules and ran npm install again but still getting the problem.

Also I'm using Visual Studio Code and when opening the project in VSC I get the message as well

```
The git repository at 'xxx' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled.
```

[here is what I get when opening the project is VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/memjx.png)

Im haven't experienced working with git before and clicking `commit all` doesn't seem to help at all.

Thanks

Comment: This is not the problem of **react** , its because your current state is different from the last commit of git. The image you shared have lots of .atom files which I think is not the part of you project

Answer (score 1):

Try running these commands, and try again:

```
git add .

git commit -am "Save before ejecting"
```

If the above solution did not work for you (e.g., due to having untracked files in your home directory which are unrelated to what you're working on), try this alternative solution before ejecting:

```
rm -rf ~/.git
```

This command will remove untracked files from your `.git` working directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
```

in order to stash all changes, in order to be able to commit them ( `git commit -m 'commit'` )
if this is answer to your question? 
If you want to unstash it/stop following just use `git checkout` * ( names of files ), and use commit afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the problem of **react** , its because your current state is different from the last commit of git. The image you shared have lots of **.atom** files,  which I think is not the part of your project

To solve I suggest to identify the files that have your changes
To see all the files that have changes use command

> git status

or you can use VS code by click on **git** from left panel to see files that have changes

[image: VS git panel]

add files that have you changes by

> git add file_path_from_root

then git commit by

> git commit -m "message"

then remove files that doesnot belongs to you by

> git stash

alternatively you can use [git Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) or [Tortoise Git](https://tortoisegit.org/download/) for GUI interfave

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to figure out the untracked files, for this purpose use

```
git status
```

after this, if you wants to keep these changes add/commit these files, by using

```
git add .
```

or `git add -A`
and then commit these file using `git commit -m "your msg"`
and if you don't want these files now or wanna use them later stash them using `git stash`
hope so using this you will get rid of untracked files.